# Matlab, Error using surf, X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex

Tags: matlab, plot, surf

i run below code, but get X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex error, any idea what is wrong?

```
 k=1;
 u = linspace(0,2*pi,72); 
 v = [-3:.2:-1,1:.2:3];
 [U,V] = meshgrid(u,v);
 r=sqrt((4*V.^-k)./(cos(U).^2+k*sin(U).^2));
 X = r.*cos(U); 
 Y = r.*sin(U);
 Z = V;
```

This is the image I want to get:

http://adasu.info/plates.png

The full code is:

```
function simple_math_functions_animation1
clc, close all, clear all

hf1=figure(1);hold on,grid on,axis equal, view([1 -1 1])
set(hf1,'Color','w');set(hf1,'Position',[300, 600, 500, 400]);
xlabel('x');ylabel('y'),zlabel('z');

 k=1;
 u = linspace(0,2*pi,72);
 v = [-3:.2:-1,1:.2:3];
 [U,V] = meshgrid(u,v);
 r=sqrt((4*V.^-k)./(cos(U).^2+k*sin(U).^2));
 X = r.*cos(U);
 Y = r.*sin(U);
 Z = V;

surf(X,Y,Z,'EdgeColor',[0.5 1. 0.2],'FaceColor',[1 0.2 0.8],'FaceAlpha',0.6);

XYZ=[reshape(X,1,prod(size(X)));
     reshape(Y,1,prod(size(Y)));
     reshape(Z,1,prod(size(Z)));
     ones(1,prod(size(Z)))];
phi=[0 : pi/20 : 50*pi];
h=[]; axis([-20 20 -20 20 -20 20]);

for beta=phi   % animation loop  *****************

    T=[cos(beta) -sin(beta) 0    0;     % rotation matrix
       sin(beta)  cos(beta) 0    0;
        0          0        1    0;
        0          0        0    1];

    XYZ1=T*XYZ;  % coordinates changing
    X1=reshape(XYZ1(1,:),size(X));Y1=reshape(XYZ1(2,:),size(Y));Z1=reshape(XYZ1(3,:),size(Z));
    pause(0.1);if ~isempty(h),delete(h);end
    h=surf(X1,Y1,Z1,'EdgeColor',[0.5 1. 0.2],'FaceColor',[0.2 0.2 0.8],'FaceAlpha',0.6);

end       % ******************************************

end
```

Comment: works for me. Are you sure you included all the code? There is no variable named C in your example.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8pXjeKXw here is full code

Comment: Still no variable `C` in the code ...

Comment: You don't need to call `clear all` at the beginning of a function, it has its own workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that complex error because `r` is complex-valued.  `r` is used in both `X` and `Y` and so when it's time to use `surf` on these inputs, you finally get that error.  That makes sense because your range of `V` has **negative** values, and when you set `k=1` for this expression:

```
r=sqrt((4*V.^-k)./(cos(U).^2+k*sin(U).^2));
```

You are effectively trying to take the square root of values in `V` and some of them are negative, and hence `r` is complex valued.  If you look at your actual image you uploaded, you are missing a `2` in the power of `V`.  Therefore:

```
r=sqrt((4*V.^2-k)./(cos(U).^2+k*sin(U).^2));
```

When I do this, then try running your code, I get this:

[image]

Comment: Look at the `r` expression between the image and what you coded.  You are missing a `2` in the power for `V`.  I've updated my answer.  Have a look.

Comment: @adska - No problem.  Consider accepting my answer :) This means that you no longer need any more help on this matter and we can move on to answering other questions.  You can do this by going to the top of my post, and go to the left, just below the up and down arrows... click on the checkmark icon.  Good luck!